# Covert Excel VBA Macro from Active Sheet to all sheets without focus

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I'm currently using a macro that autofills formulas down based on whether there is data in column 'A'. The macro works fine, just only on the current select sheet (ie the one the user is on).

Can anyone help me convert to work for all sheets in the workbook?

Formula as below:

```
Sub FillForms()
Dim WKS As Worksheet

For Each WKS In Worksheets

    Select Case UCase(WKS.Name)
    Case "Sheet1"
        Range("J3:M3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("J3:M" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    Case "Sheet2"
        Range("J3:M3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("J3:M" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    Case "Sheet3"
        Range("J3:M3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("J3:M" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    Case "Sheet4"
        Range("J3:M3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("J3:M" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    Case "Sheet5"
        Range("J3:M3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("J3:M" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    Case "Sheet6"
        Range("J3:K3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("J3:K" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    Case "[Day 3]"
        Range("J3:K3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("J3:K" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    Case "[Day 5]"
        Range("J3:K3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("J3:K" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    Case "[Day 10]"
        Range("J3:K3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("J3:K" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    Case "[Day 15]"
        Range("J3:K3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("J3:K" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    Case "[Day 20]"
        Range("J3:K3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("J3:K" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    Case Else
         'Code for other sheets
    End Select
Next WKS
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: minimal effort required, SO is not a code-writing service. See help-center!

Comment: Why `UCase`? `Case "Sheet1"` will never be reached...

Comment: @mehow there's no need to downvote. The OP has tried to write some code, it works in a fashion but not as expected, they've asked for help on why it isn't working. I think this is a fine example of a question. The OP isn't asking us to write it for them, they've asked for help, which CTS-Link has provided with a fine example (where s/he hasn't written the entire code for them)

Comment: @SilverShotBee I have not downvoted just voted to close since it's unclear what the OP is asking ( to me he is asking for additional code to be written on top of his current code with no effort whatsoever )

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
WKS.Range("J3:M3").AutoFill ...
```

instead of

```
Range("J3:M3").AutoFill ...
```

This way you specify that the range is in a specified worksheet, not in the active worksheet.

**Later edit:** Please note that `Destination` argument's references might need updated too to the specified sheet instead of the active one.

Comment: This is a better way of approaching this! +1